# Trying to use dynamic rendering extension, validation layers complain about missing renderpass

Tags: c++, graphics, vulkan

I want to use the dynamic rendering extension to finally be free of renderpasses.

However when i try to make a pipeline my validation layers yell:

`required parameter pCreateInfos[0].renderPass specified as VK_NULL_HANDLE`

For this createinfo.

```
    vk::GraphicsPipelineCreateInfo pipelineInfo{};
    pipelineInfo.stageCount = 2;
    pipelineInfo.pStages = shaderStages;
    pipelineInfo.pVertexInputState = &vertexInputInfo;
    pipelineInfo.pInputAssemblyState = &inputAssembly;
    pipelineInfo.pViewportState = &viewportState;
    pipelineInfo.pRasterizationState = &rasterizer;
    pipelineInfo.pMultisampleState = &multisampling;
    pipelineInfo.pColorBlendState = &colorBlending;
    pipelineInfo.layout = pipelineLayout;
    pipelineInfo.pDynamicState = &dynamicState;
    pipelineInfo.basePipelineHandle = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
```

I am trying to follow this example: https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan/blob/master/examples/dynamicrendering/dynamicrendering.cpp

How do I let vulkan know that I don;t need a renderpass?

Setup code

```
    vk::PhysicalDeviceDynamicRenderingFeaturesKHR dynamic_rendering = {};
    dynamic_rendering.dynamicRendering = true;

    features.pNext = &dynamic_rendering;

    // Setup general information about the current application.
    vk::ApplicationInfo program_info(
        "NeverEngine",
        VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 0),
        "No Engine",
        VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 0),
        VK_API_VERSION_1_2);
    // Create Vulkan instance to communicate with the loader.
    vk::InstanceCreateInfo create_info = {};
    create_info.pNext = &features;
    create_info.pApplicationInfo = &program_info,
    create_info.enabledLayerCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(VALIDATION_LAYERS.size()),
    create_info.ppEnabledLayerNames = VALIDATION_LAYERS.data(),
    create_info.enabledExtensionCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(required_extensions.size()),
    create_info.ppEnabledExtensionNames = required_extensions.data();

    auto [result, instance] = vk::createInstanceUnique(create_info);
    Assert(result == vk::Result::eSuccess, "Error: Failed to create instance");
```

It seems from the error messages the validation layers are version 1.2.198

Comment: Please also add the setup code. It's possible that you e.g. forgot to enable the dynamic rendering feature. And also important: What version of the validation layers are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [changelog](https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/sdk/1.2.198.1/windows/release_notes.html):

> VK_KHR_dynamic_rendering (Note: Validation Layer support is incomplete, incorrect results are possible)